# Socket io chat user dashboard chat conversation between all user and admin in individual chat user dashboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I have integrated socket io chat.While login as user.I am getting all messages between admin and all other user with in user panel. While  sending msg from user to admin conversation in admin panel comes for individual user.I want conversation between admin and user with in user dashboard.

Controller Code:

```
app.post('/saveuserchat',isLoggedIn ,function(req, res) {
     try {
            var chatModel = new chat(req.body)
            chatModel.save()
            res.sendStatus(200)
            //Emit the event
            io.emit("chat", req.body.msg_desc)
        } catch (error) {
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
   });
app.get('/getuserchat',isLoggedIn,function(req, res) {
   chat.find({}, (error, chats) => {
        res.send(chats);
    });
     });
```

Ejs code:

```
<script>
     var socket = io()
    socket.on("chat", addChat)

    $(() => {
        getChats()
    $("#send").click((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        var chatMessage = {
                 chat: $('#btn-chat-input').val(),
                 reciever: $('#adminid').val(),
                 sender: $('#userid').val(),
                 role: 'user',
                 msg_desc: $('#btn-chat-input').val(),
                 userid: $('#userid').val()


              }
            //console.log(chat);
            postChat(chatMessage);
            addChat(chatMessage);
            $('#btn-chat-input').val();
        });
    })

    function postChat(chat) {
    $.post("/saveuserchat", chat)
    }

    function getChats() {
        $.get("/getuserchat", (chats) => {
            console.log(chats);
     chats.forEach(addChat)
      })
    }
    function addChat(chatObj) {
    $("#chat_message").append(`<p class="usermsg">${chatObj.msg_desc}</p>`);

    }

</script>
```

[image: User Dashboard all user converstion with admin]